# Is this an ectopic beat?

Tags: cardiology, electrocardiography, signal-processing

First of all, I am unclear as to whether the answer to this question is a matter of fact or of opinion.
Nevertheless, I hope to find the answer.

In the image below, is the green beat considered ectopic?[image]

Comment: What do you think, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference: a normal P QRS from an EKG
[image: P and QRS from ekg]
from https://www.healio.com/cardiology/learn-the-heart/ecg-review/ecg-interpretation-tutorial/qrs-complex

The question and the different looking beat: one cannot say it is ectopic because the strip represents some sort of atrial arrhythmia.  [Atrial fibrillation](https://www.practicalclinicalskills.com/atrial-fibrillation) is the most common of these.  The beats are not regularly spaced and there is no sign of a P wave (the one produced by the atrium).

From link

> Atrial Fibrillation occurs when multiple electrical impulses occur
>   within within the atria. This chaotic electrical activity results in a
>   chaotic wave form between the QRS complexes. P waves are absent. They
>   are replaced by lower case "f" waves. No P waves means there is no PR
>   interval measurement. This rapid electrical activity overwhelms the AV
>   node causing impulses to enter the ventricular conduction system at
>   irregular points. This results in irregular R to R intervals.

"Ectopic" beat suggests there is a regular beat going on and some rogue beat elbows its way in.  In A fib they are all rogue beats - "multiple electrical impulses".  The one you see is not in structure different from the rest - there is a T for every QRS and so they are all coming from the atrium.  It is just that with that beat the S wave is deeper.  Maybe because it is so close to the T?   I bet if you ran that strip a while you would see others comparably deep.

I am betting this is homework.  What exactly is the question?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance Will.  I had the assumption that even in atrial fibrillation, there is some ventricular rhythm to be studied, given by the RR intervals of suitably "normal" beats.  Essentially I was wondering whether the size of the beat would qualify it as "not-normal," meaning not part of the intrinsic ventricular rhythm, if any.

Comment: And you are right in predicting that there are more beats with the same S-depth as the green one, though they are fairly sparse.

Comment: this isn't biology, this is medicine. go to the medicine stack exchange

Comment: Beats coming from within the ventricle look different - wide weird QRS.  Google up PVC or premature ventricular contraction to see a common type.

Comment: @4DNeuron This post is considered as on-topic. Please see [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/where-do-we-draw-the-line-for-questions-about-medicine) for further details. Also, there are tags that directly support the topic of this question, so I don't see a problem.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not AFib. March it out. (That's one of the first things to learn when studying EKG's: "march it out". It's tedious but instructive.) You'll see a pattern impossible with AFib. It's a crappy EKG tracing, but information is there. There is, however, an atrial problem.

Comment: @Will - Also, "ectopic beat" does not equal "PVC".